# How to rbind only the common columns of two data sets

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames with different number of columns each. Some of the columns are common between the 2 data frames. How can i rbind only the common columns of the two data frames to a new data frame?

i tried with `library(plyr);rbind.fill(A,B)` however it sets NA values in the columns that do not match, and this does not help me.

Thanks a lot
EC

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use `intersect` to retrieve the common columns.

```
dfr1 <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = runif(5), z = rnorm(5))
dfr2 <- data.frame(w = letters[1:5], x = 6:10, y = runif(5))
common_cols <- intersect(colnames(dfr1), colnames(dfr2))
rbind(
  subset(dfr1, select = common_cols), 
  subset(dfr2, select = common_cols)
)
```

As pointed out in the comments, you can replace the last line with

```
rbind(
  dfr1[, common_cols], 
  dfr2[, common_cols]
)
```

for a small performance and typing improvement.

```
rbind(
  dfr1[common_cols], 
  dfr2[common_cols]
)
```

also works but I think that it's a tiny bit less clear.

---

You can also use dplyr equivalents for the last step.

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(
  dfr1 %>% select({common_cols}), 
  dfr2 %>% select({common_cols})
)
```

Comment: Very succinct and understandable. +1

Comment: No need to use subset here - and generally you want to avoid programming with any function that uses non-standard evaluation.  (And I'm not sure why you'd want to use it because it's rather verbose compared to `dfr1[common_cols]`)

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution hope i got your question right

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=rnorm(100), b=rnorm(100), not=rnorm(100))
df2 <- data.frame(a=rnorm(100), b=rnorm(100))

bind1 <- bind1 <- df1[, names(df1) %in% names(df2)]
bind2 <- bind1 <- df1[, names(df2) %in% names(df1)]

rbind(bind1, bind2)
```

Comment: What happens if `df2` has columns that aren't in `df1`?

Comment: Also, the call to `subset` isn't necessary.  If you are going to use indexing later, then you can just pass them the logical vector created by `names(df1) %in% names(df2)`.

Comment: as for your first comment: if df2 has columns that aren't in df1 - they are not common and I don't want to filter them - or am I wrong? as for your second comment: right this would be better probably I did it a bit too sloppy...

Comment: If they're in df2 but not in df1 they they aren't common so you *do* want to filter them.  My point is that `%in%` isn't symmetric, whereas `intersect` is.  You'd need `bind1 <- df1[, names(df1) %in% names(df2)]` and `bind2 <- df2[, names(df2) %in% names(df1)]`.

Answer (score 0):

made my own function for my personal package: (this works also for more than 2 dataframes)

**function:**

```
fast.rbind <- function(...,method=c("fill","common"),value=NA){
    if("fill"==method[1]) {
        fun1 <- function(x,y,value=NA){
            x[setdiff(colnames(y),colnames(x))] <- value

            y[setdiff(colnames(x),colnames(y))] <- value

            return(rbind(x,y))
        }
    }

    if("common"==method[1]) {
        fun1 <- function(x,y,value=NULL){
            common_cols <- intersect(colnames(x), colnames(y))
            return(rbind(x[, common_cols,drop=F],y[, common_cols,drop=F]))
        }
    }
    return(Reduce(function(x,y){fun1(x=x,y=y,value=value)},list(...)))
}
```

**call + example data:**

```
df1 <- mtcars[1:5,1:4]
df2 <- mtcars[6:10,2:5]
df3 <- mtcars[11:15,4:7]
fast.rbind(df1,df2,df3,method="common")
fast.rbind(df1,df2,df3,value="yourDesiredFill")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a useful way to do this at scale for xlsx files

```r
# Set the path to the directory containing the xlsx files
data_folder <- "path/to/data_folder"

# List all the xlsx files in the data_folder
files <- list.files(path = data_folder, pattern = "\\.xlsx$", full.names = TRUE)

# Create a function to read the xlsx files and return column names
get_column_names <- function(file_path) {
  read_xlsx(file_path) %>% names()
}

# Get column names from all the files
column_names <- map(files, get_column_names)

# Find the common columns in all the files
common_columns <- reduce(column_names, intersect)

# Read and bind data from all the files, keeping only the common columns
combined_data <- map_df(files, ~ read_xlsx(.x) %>% select(all_of(common_columns)))
```